# How can I display my SQL database within a table format in python within my GUI?

Tags: python, sql, user-interface, pyqt4

```
def viewrow(self):
   with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as db:  
       cur = db.cursor()    
       cur.execute('select* from Values Order BY ValuesID ASC')
       roww = [cn[0] for cn in cur.description]
       tab = cur.fetchall()
       for roww in tab:
           tabb=("%2s %2s %2s %2s %2s" %(roww))
           print(tabb)
           self.l124.setText(tabb)
```

This is what I have tried so far in order to represent my database. I tried to print the rows of data out. I have also thought about using QGridLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of options within the QT-Framework (see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html for a basic introduction). You could implement q QTableView, a [QTreeView](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTreeView.html) etc. pp..

For more customizable view, you need to deal with the rather complicated Model-Controler-View paradigm in QT.
There are simpler abstractions (f.e. the [QTreeWidget](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTreeWidget.html) or the corresponding [QTableWidget](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidget.html)) which include a predefined model, so you don't need to care about the whole Model-Controller-View stack and just need to care for the view and passing your data to it. There are several tutorials available on the net. However, when it comes to speed and customization, you should go for a custom MCV solution.

Note: It would be helpful if you'd provide some requirements, so what representation of your database/rows do you prefer? What have you done so far? (I used PySide example, but the PyQT names should be the same!)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! All i require is an x number of columns and unlimited rows which will be editable. The representation I require will be relatively simple, all I would like to see is the data within the columns listed out neatly in a simple table, which could then be placed within my gui. I liked the look of Pyside however I cannot use this for the program I am trying to create, would there be a way of doing a similar thing withing Pyqt alone? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It is possible, as PyQT is just another binding to the QT-Framework. A simple example can be found [here](http://www.codeprogress.com/python/libraries/pyqt/showPyQTExample.php?index=422&key=QSqlDatabaseConnecttoMySql). This one uses QT database-layer, but you don't have to do that and can combine your solution with the QTableWidget. Check the [PyQT-Documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#details) for details, although I preferr using PySide, which is way better documented and more pythonic.